# Partitioning a dataset and repetitively subtracting off a shift, ie: folding data back onto itself.

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

I have some oscilloscope data of a repetitive experiment occurring every 50ms. At 2.5us between points every "mini-experiment" is 20,000 pts long (see plot below for a short sample).    [image]

What I want to do is partition the data according to each of the "mini-experiments" and stack all of the traces on top of each other so I can analyze the statistics of all of the experiments.  A manually generated plot of the kind of thing I'm thinking of is here (each of these is a different oscilloscope save with same trigger):

[image: If it were only one or two traces I c]ould do it manually but I have many thousands of mini-experiments I'd like to analyze and I'd like to be able to automate this somewhat.  I know how to split the data up into many smaller traces of length 'N' using "Partition[data,N]" but I don't know how to fold them back onto themselves.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have `partitions = Partition[data, 20000]`, can't you just do `ListLinePlot[ partions ]`?

Comment: that plots the original data as many separate lists but doesn't fold the data back onto itself (e.g.: so all traces start at t=0)

Comment: I think you need to describe the exact structure/format of the data in looks like.

Comment: I think we need to see some data from a (small) number of mini-experiments suitably down-sampled to say 50 points each.

Comment: What is "fold the data back on itself"? *"stack all of the traces on top of each other"* sounds like *wanting* all traces to start from `t=0`. Please clarify this by editing this into the question.

Comment: If the problem is that your data points have a time component, eg: `{t_i, v_i}`, you can plot them all on the same graph with `ListLinePlot[partitions[[;; , ;; , 2]]]`.

Comment: @Drotar  Assuming your original data is of the form `{{t1,V1},{t2,V2},...}`, I think the easiest way would be to replace all the time series with the first time series:  `ReplacePart[{i_, 1} :> partitions [[1, i, 1]] ] /@ partitions ` (with `partitions` defined in my original comment).  An alternative (possibly better for less ideal data) would be to make each time series start at zero by subtracting each time by the initial time:  `Function[dataList, 
  With[{baseVal = dataList[[1, 1]]}, 
   MapAt[# - baseVal &, {;; , 1}]@dataList]] /@ partitions`.

Comment: Thanks for all the input everyone!   @LLlAMnYP indeed, having all the "mini-traces" start at t=0 is the basic goal.   It seems my question was unclear...my goal is to reformat the data time series to start at t=0 for various kinds of analysis (not just plotting).  I'm trying to figure out how to upload sample data for people to experiment with. Thanks!

Comment: @drotar good to hear. Have a think about it, and I'll look forward to reopening this question on Monday :-)